# Функция мешает работать боту

Tags: python, discord, disnake

У меня бот, у которого типа график. Функция для того, чтобы проверять, закончился у одного время, или нет. Вот код:

```
async def check_timestamp():
    while True:
        try:
            with open("list.json", "r") as file:
                data = json.load(file)

            current_time = int(time.time())
            for username, (timestamp, userid) in list(data["time"].items()):
                if current_time >= timestamp:
                    user = bot.get_user(int(userid))
                    await user.send("This is training time!")
                    del data["time"][username]
            
            time.sleep(1)

            with open("list.json", "w") as file:
                json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
            
            del data

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(1)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Hello, world!")
    asyncio.create_task(check_timestamp())
```

Если убрать `create_task()`, тогда все будет работать. В чем у меня ошибка?

Comment: если ошибка простая, понять и простить. давно ничего не кодил, решил сделать простенького бота для своего сервера.

Comment: Ошибка то есть? Код просто так не работать не может

Comment: Нету. Никаких ошибок в консоли не выдает.

Comment: time.sleep(1) -->await asyncio.sleep(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep()` блокирует весь процесс, а `asyncio.sleep()` - только конкретную функцию. Вероятно, у вас возникает исключение на каждой итерации цикла, поэтому процесс почти все время спит. Попробуйте вызвать `print(e, flush=true)` - это заставит python "протолкнуть" данные в поток вывода перед следующей операцией. Скорее всего из-за `time.sleep` вы просто не видите исключение

Comment: ответ сергей ш, но с объяснением.

Comment: верно, я использовал за основу предложение Сергея